# Regular Expression Ending with a certain character should avoid multiple occurrence of that character before

Tags: python, regex

I have a data which looks something like this

```
<workorder id = "124"
       issue = "broken hood"
       level = "minor"
       comment = " This will be some random text <imp>random text<imp>
         <role>Important<role> So this is goingto be fixed!"
>
</workorder> Some more random text
```

I need to capture everything from the starting '<workorder' till the ending '>' tag. The problem is, my regular expression stops when it comes at the second imp tag's '>' closing brace. See the figure for more details.

[image]

I am using regex101 website to test my regular expression, and the settings are Python, with the flags (global, single line and multiline). Single line essentially means that the . operator will match end of line too.

Here is my regular expression

```
 *(<workorder.*?>$)(.?)
```

There is a space before the first asterisk. Is there a way to capture everything until the '>' before the  ?

The data set may also look like this too :
Here the '>' is beside the " character

```
<workorder id = "124"
       issue = "broken hood"
       level = "minor"
       comment = " This will be some random text <imp>random text<imp>
         <role>Important<role> So this is goingto be fixed!">
</workorder> Some more random text
```

or like this
Here the '>' is beside the / character

```
<workorder id = "124"
       issue = "broken hood"
       level = "minor"
       comment = " This will be some random text <imp>random text<imp>
         <role>Important<role> So this is going to be fixed!"/> 
Some more random text
```

or like this
Here the '>' is beside the / character but in next line

```
<workorder id = "124"
       issue = "broken hood"
       level = "minor"
       comment = " This will be some random text <imp>random text<imp>
         <role>Important<role> So this is going to be fixed!"
/> 
Some more random text
```

Comment: Why not `(?s)<workorder\b.*?</workorder>` , or just `(?s)<workorder.*?</workorder>`? Can `</workorder>` be missing in the input?

Comment: yes, the </workorder> can be missing. See the last update I made. Sorry for not formulating the question properly.

Comment: `<workorder.*?(?:/>|</workorder>)` with `re.S` [should do](https://regex101.com/r/MUDwlf/2) for the above examples. If there can be more self-closing tags in between, this won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can find an XML/HTML parser for that. If you want regex, you can try this:

```
(<workorder[\s\S]*?(?:<\/workorder>|\/>))
```

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/lohcRd/1).

Where

- Outer `(...)` - Capture the result
- `<workorder` - Match the starting string
- `[\s\S]*?` - Match any characters in a non-greedy way so that you won't be spanning multiple workorder groups.
- `(?:<\/workorder>|\/>)` - Match the ending string whether it is `</workorder>` or `/>`.

Answer (score 0):

This PCRE RegEx should help you extract the data from **<** till **>**

[image]

```
<.*>
```

Flags should be:

```
g --> Global
i --> Case Insensitive
s --> Single Line
```